# Need read XML and show it and save on Local storage.

Tags: xml, html, rss, local-storage, feed

I need to read XML data and show this in HTML and at the same time save it in localStorage.

When the user is ofline I need show the content using localStorage.

(*NOTE:* without PHP)
(*NOTE:*  when user have internet read and show new items )

Does anyone have a good tutorial or any helpful website?

Comment: You mention PHP. If this question involves PHP, you should probably remove the rss tag and add the php tag.

Comment: do you need help converting XML to HTML in the browser? do you need help storing XML data in localStorage? do you need help figuring out when to use localStorage and when to work "online"? which one of the three would you like a tutorial on?

Comment: I need show the xml in html withow php and save it on local storage

Answer (score 3):

I found this article/tutorial. 
It shows how to parse and save a xml file.
And how you can query it offline.

It is done by using javascript.

Article is on mantascode.com by Mantascode and describes how to parse a xml file to localstorage.
using a launch.html to parse xml file using java script.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

This page will parse and save books.xml into the users browser<br />
specifically into html5 localStorage<br />
The xml file being pushed is called books.xml<br />
<br />
<a href="books.xml">books.xml</a>
<br />
<a href="OFFLINE.html">OFFLINE.html</a>


<script type="text/javascript">  

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var xmlRowString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes.length; i++)
{
if ( xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'book' )
{
for ( var k = 0 ; k < xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; k++ )
{
if ( xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[k].nodeName == 'author' )
{
xmlRowString += "<book><author>"+xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[k].textContent+"</author>";
}
if ( xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[k].nodeName == 'title' )
{
xmlRowString += "<title>"+xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[k].textContent+"</title>";
}
if ( xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[k].nodeName == 'description' )
{
xmlRowString += "<description>"+xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[k].textContent+"</description></book>";
}
}
}
if ( xmlRowString === "" )
{
}
else
{
//Here for each book we populate a local stoage row
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined' ) 
{
alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.');
} 
else 
{
try                          
{ 
localStorage.setItem(i, xmlRowString);
} 
catch (e) 
{
alert("save failed!");
if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) 
{
alert('Quota exceeded!'); //data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
}
}
}
xmlRowString = "";  
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And a Offline.html to query the local stored xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search local storage</title>
</head>

<body>

This page will allow the user to search the content saved in your local storage.<br />
Search By Author name, results will be returned by book title.<br />


<form action="OFFLINE.html" method="get">
  Search By Author : <input type="text" name="txtA" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
<br />
<br />


<div id="results_ID"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var localStorageRow = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) ;

var author_query = getUrlVars()["txtA"];

if (typeof(author_query) == "undefined" || author_query === "" )
{
}
else
{
for ( var i = 0 ; i < localStorage.length;  i++)
{
var localStorageRow = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) ;

if (window.DOMParser)
{
parser=new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(localStorageRow,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(localStorageRow);
} 

for ( var k = 0 ; k < xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes.length ; k++ )
{
if ( xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes[k].nodeName === "author" )
{

var auth_row = xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes[k].textContent;         
var authMatch = auth_row.match(new RegExp(author_query, "i"));
if ( authMatch )
{
//CANNOT USE XPATH(a lot of browsers dont support this) 
//YOU HAVE TO LOOP THOUGH ELEMENTS (again) TO GET TITLE
/*
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate('//title', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );  
for ( var q=0 ; q < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; q++ )  
{  
document.getElementById("results_ID").innerHTML += nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(q).textContent+"<br />";
}  
*/

for ( var p = 0 ; p < xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes.length ; p ++ )
{
if ( xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes[p].nodeName == 'title' )
{
document.getElementById("results_ID").innerHTML += xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes[p].textContent+"<br />";
}
}

}
}
}
}
}

//GET URL VARS function
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Markup of books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

[Here you will find the article](http://mantascode.com/?p=594)

Title of article:
Javascript: How to parse xml, write to html5 local storage, then read from local storage, and allow user to search content.

Comment: Once the link goes dead, your answer will be virtually useless. Post some actual information you found in the article or at least mention the title and author so it can be found in a different location.

Comment: added html and books.xml. Read the article using link for more info.

This is not my code, credits go to mantascode on mantascode.com