# Where to put my code "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I need to retrieve data from an api but the data is only available in XML.
I was told to retrieve the data to display it in HTML via this topic: [How to retrieve values from xml file and display in html webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834660/how-to-retrieve-values-from-xml-file-and-display-in-html-webpage)

Until I thought I was right, I changed the code with the info I needed and got the famous error in the Google Chrome console: (index):30 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So in my index.html file I added this PHP code at the beginning :
`<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'); ?>` (I use the * for the tests only, to publish my code I will set the exact URL).

My page still shows this error, so I'm wondering if it's really on my code that I should put this, or on the recipient's server?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the interaction you're describing.  You're trying to enable CORS in your own server-side application?  What is "the recipient's server"?  CORS errors happen when a page running in the browser tries to make an AJAX request to a 3rd party resource.  Is that what's happening here?  Or is the page trying to access *your own* server?  Or something else?

Comment: @David Thanks for your feedback. To make it simple, the XML file that I am trying to retrieve the data from is not on my server. It is a link to an external server, and we have access to a list of data in XML format. On our side, we have to format this data, so I tried to retrieve the info via what I put as a link above.

Comment: It is not up to YOU to set the access headers. It is up to the TARGET. If they are not set, you are SOL unless you use your php/server as a proxy for the api on the other server

Comment: If the 3rd party server doesn't allow CORS requests then there's nothing you can do to change that from your end.  What you *can* do is request the resource from your server-side code and deliver the results to the client, essentially using your own server as a proxy for the request.

Comment: What does "_we have access to a list of data in XML format_" exactly means?