# How to save image locally in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a website for data entry. For the purpose of illustration, let the page contains a text box and a file uploader. User browsers afile and enter data in text box. In the mean time, if the connection to internet loses, I want to save the data locally and retrieve it when the next time user opens the browser.

I've used localstorage. But not sure how to save image chosen in the file uploader control.

Please some one help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You would probably have to rely on HTML5 and convert the image to base64, and then save the base64 string to localStorage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940586/can-you-use-html5-local-storage-to-store-a-file-if-not-how