# How to save video downloaded from server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm downloading a video from a server using JavaScript XHR (Angular $http GET in particular, with response type 'blob')

How should I save this to chrome application's local storage?

Currently using an Angular wrapper on HTML5 filesystem API https://github.com/maciel310/angular-filesystem

```
writeFileInput: function(filename, file, mimeString) {
        var def = $q.defer();

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var buf = e.target.result;

            $timeout(function() {
                fileSystem.writeArrayBuffer(filename, buf, mimeString).then(function() {
                    safeResolve(def, "");
                }, function(e) {
                    safeReject(def, e);
                });
            });
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        return def.promise;
    }
```

This is the code which saves files. But this is designed when the file is received from an input. Since I'm not receiving this file from input, this is not working (specifically `readAsArrayBuffer()`.

It is showing error as
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: yes that is to big. Please see my answer I updated it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want through something like this with `localStorage`

You are going to want to use [File System Api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem)

I know you say you want `localStorage` but most likely you don't have enough space if you're trying to store videos.

[This answer relates this this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940618/2218253)

Please see This 
Answer

```
You said, "It's around 15 MB".
```

That is way to big to be storing to local storage.

Comment: No, I've sufficient space.

Comment: How big our the videos?

Comment: Follow up question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531428/chrome-apps-how-to-save-blob-content-to-filesystem-in-the-background

Comment: Would you mind accepting this questions answer? In the meantime I will provide an answer for your new question. Thank you :)