# Detect start of download start / file transfer from client side only

Tags: javascript, forms

I noticed that there is a question before asking how to
"[Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)".

This requires the server to send a cookie in order to complete the steps.
However, I want to detect if the browser receives file only on client side, as I cannot modify anything on the server side.

The problem I am encountering is that I have to download many zip files from a website. The zip files are dynamically generated so there is no URL to download until I submit the request. First, I write a for loop to do that as follows.

```
function myfunc(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("form").submit();
    },2000*(i)
}
for (i=1; i<4; i++) {
myfunc(i);
} //i
```

But there is a chance that before the browser receives the first file `(i=1)`, the browser will have already submitted the form requesting the second file `(i=2)` and cancel the request of first file. So I have to ensure the first file has started before requesting the second file.

**`ajax` seems not to be an option** as it seems to be unable to handle zip file download.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: Maybe you can download the file into user's localStorage, you can have control over it. I haven't done this before, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940586/can-you-use-html5-local-storage-to-store-a-file-if-not-how) might give you some directions.

Comment: @Populus - that suggested duplicate is UPloading, not DOWNloading. It's not going to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
You can also ise an ajax call to get a base64 string of the zip and then clientside convert it to a blob in html5. But that requires to base64 encode the file server side and it increases the file size by around 33%.

---

I would make an ajax call that checks is the file is already generated after starting the download with a timer:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'generatedfileurl',
    success: function() {
        alert('File found.');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('File not found.');
    }
});
```

Then when the file is found I'd wait a few seconds and then start download nr2 since I assume that file nr1 is already downloading since it has already been generated.

It's far from ideal, I'd definitely recommend using cookies or something else serverside.